# Add class to previous element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding classes namely hide_some_features,show_some_features in each loop. Now i want to add class to feature_suffix having next only hide_some_features class. I tried with  `$(this).closest('.feature_suffix').addClass('test-class');` which is not working.

```
 $('.variations_form input:radio[name=attribute_pa_1]').each(function() {
     if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-feature-value'), disabledFetaureValue) < 0) {
         $(this).closest('.cc-selector').addClass('hide_some_features');
         $(this).closest('.feature_suffix').addClass('test-class');
     } else {
         $(this).closest('.cc-selector').addClass('show_some_features');
     }
 })
```

;
[image]

I want to add class to highlighted place

Comment: Question is not clear for me, can you please explain more?

Comment: can you share the html as text not as image

Comment: Simple is that I want to add a class feature_suffix near with hide_some_features

Comment: I think , question is to just add class .feature_suffix to previous div whenever the next div contains .hide_some_features  ?? is it ?

Comment: Use parent() and prev() instead of closest? https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: try this, `$(this).closest('.cc-selector').prev().addClass('hide_some_features');` becuase `closest()` method fine only parent div and you want to select outside of parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` wont work here because the target element is not an ancestor of the element that fires the event. Use the below:

```
$(this).closest('.cc-selector').prev('.feature_suffix').addClass('test-class');
```

[image]

Comment: Really you are a star. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the closest `cc-selector`, then see whether it has `hide_some_features`, if so then add the new class to its previous sibling

```
$(this).closest('.cc-selector').filter('.hide_some_features').prev('.feature_suffix').addClass('test-class');
```

Comment: P Johnty Love you :) Really genious